# Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'. This shows while I try to run wordcount job on hadoop on win 10

Tags: java, hadoop

The job would start but just get stuck and wont do anything. The files and job info are as follows:
**1. Job Information on cmd**

```
PS C:\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1> hadoop jar C:\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.2.1.jar wordcount /input/senbad.txt /output
2023-04-15 14:03:47,011 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2023-04-15 14:03:47,856 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/shekh/.staging/job_1681547354686_0002
2023-04-15 14:03:47,960 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2023-04-15 14:03:48,095 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2023-04-15 14:03:48,150 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2023-04-15 14:03:48,176 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2023-04-15 14:03:48,189 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2023-04-15 14:03:48,286 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2023-04-15 14:03:48,302 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1681547354686_0002
2023-04-15 14:03:48,303 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2023-04-15 14:03:48,498 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2023-04-15 14:03:48,499 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2023-04-15 14:03:48,969 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1681547354686_0002
2023-04-15 14:03:49,014 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://LAPTOP-SEF3N6DS:8088/proxy/application_1681547354686_0002/
2023-04-15 14:03:49,015 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1681547354686_0002
```

**2. core site config**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**3. hdfs site config**

```
<configuration>
<property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>C:\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1\data\dfs\namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>C:\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1\data\dfs\datanode</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

**4. mapred site config**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**5. yarn site config**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>  
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

I created a resource-types.xml file in the path where all xml files are located and i reffered to the answer in this link

[How do I fix a "resouce-types.xml" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664467/how-do-i-fix-a-resouce-types-xml-error)

**resource-type config**

```
<configuration>
  <resources>
    <resourceType name="GPU" units="NONE">
      <schedulerInclude>true</schedulerInclude>
      <yarnInclude>true</yarnInclude>
    </resourceType>
    <resourceType name="FPGA" units="NONE">
      <schedulerInclude>true</schedulerInclude>
      <yarnInclude>true</yarnInclude>
    </resourceType>
  </resources>
</configuration>
```

My friends which dont have this resource-type file were able to run the job fine but I am having this issue.

Comment: That line isn't an error.... If your job fails, open `The url to track the job` link. For example, if jobs are stuck, maybe YARN processes aren't actually running

Comment: @OneCricketeer when i run jps command on cmd all 5 operations are running

Comment: Okay, and when you open YARN UI? You see your job? But how many healthy nodes? How much cluster memory is available?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, This helped me solve my error. In my case the health report
from http://localhost:8088/cluster/nodes/unhealthy indicated a directory that had permission issues.
Saved me a lot of trouble.

This was the origin solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64079458/14028754